# Using Silverlight.FX Window for MVVM as a Silverlight 3.0 Page?

Tags: silverlight-3.0, mvvm, wcf-ria-services, silverlight.fx

I'm creating a Silverlight 3.0 MVVM application using Silverlight.FX but my View is actually using the Silverlight navigation system, a Page. Following [Nikhil's example](http://www.nikhilk.net/NET-RIA-Services-ViewModel-Pattern.aspx), my View should derive from the Silverlight.FX Window class.

What's the best approach to making a Window that also supports the Page functionality or is there something that already does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discovered the Page and PageFrame classes of Silverlight.FX.  These classes have the same basic functionality as the Silverlight navigation types but with support for the binding I was looking for.

```
xmlns:fxnav="clr-namespace:SilverlightFX.UserInterface.Navigation;assembly=SilverlightFX"
...
<fxnav:PageFrame x:Name="_frame"
                 IsIntegratedWithBrowser="True"
                 DefaultUri="StartView"
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

I'm having trouble grabbing the parent container from the Pages' code-behind (unlike the Silverlight 3.0 Page) but I shouldn't need it once I remove the Click handler and fully switch to MVVM anyway.

Comment: Indeed, ideally the individual pages don't reach out into the parent view that contains the PageFrame, as this introduces less than ideal coupling.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth to mention that PageFrame's default PageLoader component automatically mapping all pages available. There is no way to use new UriMapping component from Silverlight 3 with SilverlightFX's PageFrame. So, if your page is named as MySilverlightPage.xaml (and corresponding page class has the same name), it will be available at "mysilverlight" address.

P.S. I decided to mention it, because it was not clear for me when I tried to use SilverlightFX first time.